# How to refer to Answerer when responding to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

When I respond to a comment that's not the immediate predecessor of my comment, I'd like to include the commenter's @ handle so it's clear who I am responding to.  However, since you are constrained from having only one @ handle, I can't reference the answerer as well.  Is there an equivalent of OP (original poster) for the person who wrote the answer that it well understood on the StackExchange network?

Update: One workable solution is simply to prefix the second @ handle with a period; that way you can clearly indicate that these are users you're talking about (which, with some handles is not obvious).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Sheesh.  Who's going to read all that?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - not exactly what I meant - I know about notifications, I just wanted a term for referring back to the answerer, and I didn't know if there was a specific convention.

Comment: DEAR SIR OR MA'AM I HAVE RECENTLY COME INTO A LARGE SUM OF REPUTATION AND WOULD LIKE TO SHARE THIS WITH YOU... *(that is how you should address answerers)*

Comment: See point #10 in the duplicated question. It says exactly what happenes to `@name` if _name_ is the author of the post you are commenting; it also says what happens if you use two @-references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are commenting on the answer, the person who answered *will* be notified. No need to prefix their username with `@` or even use their username at all.

You can simply use their username if you want to be clear who you are referring to.

To clarify - a comment on a post will notify the writer of the post, name mentioned or not. Use `@` as a prefix to a username will notify that user, so long as they were involved in the post (meaning they have commented or edited the post).

Comment: The help shown when writing a comment says, "The post author will always be notified of your comment."

Comment: .@kiamlaluno - I know that.  Reread @MrLister's comment.  I wanted to know how to write clearly, not how to notify two people.  Maybe I'll just use the . before the @ like I did in this comment - that works.

Comment: @ScottWilson If you use `@` to refer the user who wrote the post you are commenting, that will be automatically removed. It is all described in the question I suggested as duplicated.